# Change the positioning of bullets in a unordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have ul bulleted list, is it possible to change position of the bullet in the list ?

For example this list below:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee - A brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans, which are the seeds of berries from the Coffea plant</li>
  <li>Tea - An aromatic beverage commonly prepared by pouring hot or boiling water over cured leaves of the Camellia sinensis, an evergreen shrub (bush) native to Asia</li>
</ul>
```

Should display as

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking to do. The code you posted looks like the image you posted

Comment: The position of the bullets is in the middle i want to move it slightly to the top

Comment: Only difference I see is maybe a pixel or two difference. Is that what you're asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pseudo-element instead of `li`'s bullet.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

ul li:before {
  content: "•";
  font-size:20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee - A brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans, which are the seeds of berries from the Coffea plant</li>
  <li>Tea - An aromatic beverage commonly prepared by pouring hot or boiling water over cured leaves of the Camellia sinensis, an evergreen shrub (bush) native to Asia</li>
</ul>
```